# Adding string to array of char *

Tags: c++, arrays, c++11

I would like to know how to add a string to array of char*

```
#define FROM    "<rasulasath@Tester.com>"
#define TO      "<rasulasath@gmail.com>"
#define CC      "<rasulasath@gmail.com>"
#define SUBJECT "TESTING SUBJECT"

string testing("USING variables");
const char * c = "Subject: ";

static const char *payload_text[]={
"To: " TO "\n","From: " FROM "\n","Cc: " CC "\n",c "\n",
"\n", /* empty line to divide headers from body, see RFC5322 */
SUBJECT "\n",
"\n",
"Testing the msg.\n",
"Check RFC5322.\n",
NULL
   };
```

I would like to add either `c` or the variable testing to the array of payload_test[]
or is there other way to create the array paylod_text[] with user insiated variables.

Comment: you are #defining so many things why not #define subject and body too ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to add testing then just put it in the parameters as

```
testing.c_str()
```

Also one more way is there

```
string body="Testing the msg.\n";
body+=testing;
body+="Bye ....";
```

And to put in array use

```
body.c_str();
```

Answer (score 1):

Why not use a dynamically allocated array?

```
char **email = malloc(sizeof(*email) * 6);
email[0] = "To: " TO "\n";
...
char buf[256];
snprintf(buf, sizeof(buf), "%s \n", c);
email[3] = strdup(buf);
..
```

Don't forget to free any string created by strdup() after use.

Comment: Is this the same as
static const char *payload_text[]={"To: " TO "\n","From: " FROM "\n","Cc: " CC "\n",SUBJECT "\n","\n",c "\n","\n","Testing the msg.\n","Check RFC5322.\n",NULL };

char **email = malloc(sizeof(*email) * 6);
char buf[256];
snprintf(buf, sizeof(buf), "To: %s \n", toAddress);
email[0] = strdup(buf);
snprintf(buf, sizeof(buf), "Subject: %s \n", emailSubject);
email[1] = strdup(buf);
snprintf(buf, sizeof(buf), "Message: %s \n", emailMessages);
email[2] = strdup(buf);
email[6]=NUL

Answer (score 0):

I'd prefer using `string` for `payload_text` instead. then you can easily append characters and other strings t it. and latter `payload_text.c_str()` it if underlying library needs `char*`

there is `boost::format()`. You can use it to replace `%1%`, `%2%` with your subject and body. like `boost::format("SOME STRING %1% AND THEN %2%") % subject % body`

Answer (score 0):

To do this natively in C (versus using the C++ STL classes), you can use strcat:

```
char* buffer = malloc((strlen(c) + strlen(payload_text) + 1) * sizeof(char));
strcpy(buffer, payload_text);
strcat(buffer, c);
```

This are only valid if you're sure the input is null-terminated and contains no internal nulls.  Otherwise use strncpy and strncat.

To do this in C++ using the STL classes:

```
string result = string(payload_text);
result += testing;
```